# Count the number of times an item was dragged

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to count each time an item is dragged into the dragable area and increase the counter inside the input field each time it happens.

Here is what I have as of now:

```
function cancel(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    return false;
}

var dragItems = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable=true]');

for (var i = 0; i < dragItems.length; i++) {
    addEvent(dragItems[i], 'dragstart', function (event) {
        // store the ID of the element, and collect it on the drop later on
        event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.alt);
    });
}

var drop = document.querySelector('.drop-items');
var droplist = document.querySelector('.items-listed-rc');

// Tells the browser that we *can* drop on this target
addEvent(drop, 'dragover', cancel);
addEvent(drop, 'dragenter', cancel);

addEvent(drop, 'drop', function (e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); // stops the browser from redirecting off to the text.

    this.innerHTML += '<p>' + e.dataTransfer.getData('Text') + '<input type="text" class="counter-items"></p>';
    return false;
    return false;
});
```

And here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/czbHM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try this:

```
 addEvent(drop, 'drop', function (e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); // stops the browser from redirecting off to the text.
    var thatText = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
    if (!this.innerHTML.match(thatText)) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        var text = document.createTextNode(thatText);
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.className = "counter-items";
        input.value = "1";
        input.type = 'text';
        p.appendChild(text);
        p.appendChild(input);
        this.appendChild(p);
    } else {
        var childs = this.children;
        console.log(childs);

        function addValue(childs) {
            var thisValue = childs[i].children[0].value;
            childs[i].children[0].value = parseInt(thisValue, 10) + 1;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
            if (thatText == "Scissors" && childs[i].innerText == "Scissors") {
                addValue(childs);

            } else if (thatText == "Hand" && childs[i].innerText == "Hand") {
                addValue(childs);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I have to say you were quite far from the solution.
One of the main problems was the use of `this.innerHTML += ....` since it doesn't update the document after load you have to create actual elements with javascript.

The rest is a kind of a switch. If you want to add more items you can add elseIfs or use a switch.
[You can check out the updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/czbHM/5/)

Comment: This almost correct, however could not duplicate the field of each item, will increase the counter each time the item is draggable.
Thanks.

Comment: @maria sorry i did not understand what yiu need from you comment

Comment: The event is creating new tabs each dragged item, I wanted only one tab was created and sometimes increase the counter.

Comment: you are wayyy off then. you had to id the pictures in some way and label the items then you have to check which item was added  and add 1 to its value

Comment: example... Drag Scissors = [Scissors 1] , Drag Scissors again... [Scissors 2] 
in one tab

Comment: @Maria here are you codezzz